# Cant load real-time data from tws

Tags: interactive-brokers, tws

I can't get real-time tick with API for GBP.CHF@IDEALPRO/ My log:

```
0:53:36:282 <- 9-8-1073741829-0-GBP-CASH--0-----CHF---0---
10:53:36:282 <- 1-11-1073741830-0-GBP-CASH--0-----CHF---0-233,236,258-0-0--
10:53:36:282 -> ---R4-2-1073741830-321-Error validating request.-'bX' : cause - Please enter exchange-
10:53:36:283 <- 1-11--1073741830-0-GBP-CASH--0-----CHF---0--1-0--
10:53:36:283 -> ---S4-2--1073741830-321-Error validating request.-'bX' : cause - Please enter exchange-
10:53:36:318 <- 9-8-1073741831-0-GBP-CASH--0-----CHF---0---
```

Nothing incoming from tws. Please help.

Comment: It would help if you showed us your code. It looks like IB doesn't know which exchange you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your log compared to my log.

```
1-11-1073741830-0-GBP-CASH--0  ---        --CHF---0-233,236,258-0-0--

1-11-1         -0-GBP-CASH--0.0---IDEALPRO--CHF---0-233-0-0--
```

You just forgot the exchange.

```
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = "GBP"
contract.secType = "CASH"
contract.exchange = "IDEALPRO"
contract.currency = "CHF"

app.reqMktData(1, contract, "233", False, False, None)
```

I'm not sure about your generic tick list, not all type are available for forex.   I just threw in 233 to see if it would cause an error but it worked.